# How to make a Tab type simple component in React

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-type-ui-lfmokg
I wanted to create a simple Tab type script for below html structure.
on click of Button Item 1 , only  div className="item1 infosection"  and  div className="item1 Data"  should visible.
on click of Button Item 2 , only  div className="item2 infosection" and  div className="item2 Data"  should visible.
Please Help

```
<div>
      <div className="item1 infosection">item1 Info</div>
      <div className="item2 infosection">item2 Info</div>
      <Button>Item 1</Button>
      <Button>Item 2</Button>
      <div className="item1 Data">item1 Data</div>
      <div className="item2 Data">item2 Data</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By searching online e.g. for "react tab component", you can find the following:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-tabs-component
- https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-tab-component-react/

By looking at these tutorials, you will find that you can [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to keep track of the currently active tab and change the state accordingly once one of your buttons gets pressed. Depending on the state, you can then show or hide your other components.

Comment: As per  UI requirement above type Tab libraries can't use.

Comment: These are no tab libraries but tutorials on how to create such components yourself. You can use them to learn and to understand how to implement your own requirement. Essentially, you need one ’useState’ storing a number for the currently active tab, by click on one of the buttons this state is changed and your info and data should check if the right tab is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function TabsComponant(props) {
  const [itemOne, setItemOne] = useState(false);
  const [itemTwo, setItemTwo] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {itemOne && <div className="item1">item1 Info</div>}
      {itemTwo && <div className="item2">item2 Info</div>}
      <Button onClick={() => setItemOne(!itemOne)}>Item 1</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => setItemTwo(!itemTwo)}>Item 2</Button>
      {itemOne && <div className="item1">item1 Data</div>}
      {itemTwo && <div className="item2">item2 Data</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-type-ui-forked-429xo2?file=/src/tabs.js:84-621)

Comment: its working for each button, but expected output is , only one tab item should visible at once other one should be hide. should work same as bootstrap or other standard Tabs

Comment: What do you mean by "only one tab item should visible at once other one should be hide"

Comment: Means , above code is working like just Hide and show each items together. 
I wanted, whenever tab1 is active then tab2  must be disabled/hidden and vice versa. exactly like normal tab

Comment: Well, at this point, I am pretty sure you can figure out how to do that on your own

Comment: Got it . thanks for your response & time
https://codesandbox.io/s/tab-type-button-with-splitted-tab-content-section-pyffe6?file=/src/Tabs.js